# What is the {bar}=foo declaration syntax in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've seen people with the following syntax in CoffeeScript.

```
{variable} = something_else
```

What does this do?

Comment: Can't you try it yourself at [CoffeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)?

Comment: Yes, you can try it by visiting http://coffeescript.org/ and clicking to the `Try Coffeescript` button at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Destructuring Assignment:

http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring

```
// From this coffescript
{a,b} = [1,2]

// the following javascript is generated:

var a, b, _ref;
_ref = [1, 2], a = _ref.a, b = _ref.b;
```